# Assumptions in order to perform ANOVA test

Tags: anova

I have a question where I am to circle all of the true statements.

The question:

What assumptions must be true in order to perform the ANOVA test? Circle all that are true.

I am given the options:

1)The height of each plant must be independent.

2)There must be at least 20 plants in each group, no matter if the distribution of heights is normal or not.

3)The variances of height must be the same at each altitude in the population.

Am I correct with my choices of 1 and 3?

My explanation for my choices:

1) ANOVA testing requires an independence of cases, therefore the heights of each plant must be independent to be used.

2) This is not an answer because it states that the distribution doesn't matter. From what I've learned, not having a normal distribution would mean that the ANOVA test tells us nothing.

3) This is based on the ANOVA test needing homoscedasticity. So the variances in height needs to be the same.

How is my reasoning? Please correct my thinking if I went wrong somewhere.

Comment: I don't see why 2 is required.

Comment: @MichaelChernick My choices are only 1, and 3. For the explanation part I was explaining why 2 was not an answer.

Comment: Standard ANOVA requires normality but if not there are non-parametric alternatives.

Comment: @MichaelChernick If the normality isn't the problem with 2, then is it the part about sizes that is incorrect about the statement? Does ANOVA testing not require a minimum number of samples to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANOVA has three assumptions:

1) homoscedasticity of dependent variable (equality of variances among group)

2) dependent variable is normally distributed within each group

3) each observation in the sample is independent from all other.

Note: assumptions always concern the nature of the population distribution. It is common for the sample to deviate slightly from a normal distribution. Even samples of size  50-100 drawn from a normal distribution often don't look precisely normal.

ANOVA is fairly robust against non-normality of the groups. That means that the real type I error rate will still be close to what you intended. For example, some may say that for $n > 20$ some skewness in the distribution may be acceptable and for $n > 50$ more severely skewed distributions may be acceptable. However, since this is up to the researcher, everyone has their own standards. ANOVA, however, may generally be executed with less than 20 subjects in the sample.

Therefore, 1) and 3) are actual assumptions; 2) is not correct

Remark: in contrast to linear regression ANOVA has no linearity assumption.